# General mail failure when trying to use Workbook.SendMail to recipient

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to fill in a `recipient` or `e-mail-adress` in the `.SendMail-Function` I get following error:

> Run-time error '1004': General mail failure. Quit Microsoft Excel, restart the mail system, and try again.

I've already tried the suggested solution in the error-code and multiple possible spellings and combinations of the name.

```
Sub send_mail()


ActiveWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:="Last Name, First Name"


End Sub
```

Comment: If your Recipient was invalid then you'd get the following error message: `Run-time error '1004': Unknown recipient name found in the recipient list. Use a valid name and try again.` Your code works properly on my side so it must be some sort of connectivity/tech issue. Sorry, not sure how to fix it as I cannot recreate it on my side. Maybe this link will help [link](http://www.repairmsexcel.com/blog/resolve-general-mail-failure-excel-error)

Comment: Is your Outlook on When you run this code ?

Comment: Thank you Justyna. It's possible that the reason is in my setup. I tried on a corporate machine. This could cause this problems. Thank you @Mikku aswell. I tried with outlook on and off.